# Modify local users property description in Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, user-interface, winapi, ansible, adsi

I would like to modify the description property from local users.
I can retrieve all local users name and description in two ways.

One using *WMI Win32_UserAccount class*:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" | Select-Object -Property name, description | FL
```

And one using *ADSI*:

```
$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computername"
$Users = $adsi.Children | Where-Object {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}
ForEach ($u in $Users) {
    $u | Select-Object -Property Name, Description
}
```

However, I can't figure out how using commands similar to the ones above I can modify the local user property description. I did research and only found out how to do *GETS* and not *SETS*.
My final objective is to put this code in an Ansible playbook and run it in several remote servers. If you have an idea of how to solve this or how to help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Upgrade to PowerShell version 5.1 and use [Set-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1)  ;-)

Comment: what property do you want to change?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `Description`  ;-)

Comment: Probably helps to read huh lol thanks @olaf

Comment: if you switch back to using `Get-WmiObject`, then the `.Description` property lists both `{get;set;}` for its definition. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with ADSI can be very tricky but, its super helpful since it usually doesnt rely on 3rd party modules.

Without going super in depth on `ADSI`, heres the easiest way you can change, or add a value to a property, the description property in this case:

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:Computername"
$User = $adsi.Children.Find('Abraham')
$User.Description = "Hi, this is a description"
$User.SetInfo()
```

Using `$User.SetInfo` method, we can write the changes to the database. It's not a method you would get either when piping to a `Get-Member`. Unfortunately, it's one that you would need to know already. Using *Dot Notation* we can reference the property you'd like to change, then assigning it a value just like we would when assigning a value to a variable: `$var = value`.